# How can I get Eclipse / PyDev to ignore alternatives to cls?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have inherited some code that uses klass instead of PyDev's preferred cls:

```
def func(klass):
    # do something that doesn't reference klass
    return True
```

PyDev issues a warning that there is an unused parameter `klass`, which it wouldn't do if we used the parameter `cls`.

Is there an easy way to let PyDev know that `klass` is the same thing as `cls`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using PyDev's built-in code analysis, go to Preferences > Pydev > Editor > Code Analysis, and switch to the 'Unused' tab.  At the bottom is a text field containing a list of variable names to ignore if unused.  Add `klass` to that list and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

The only unused name Pydev doesn't warn about is `_`.

`cls` is the name used for the first argument in `classmethod`s, but that doesnt seem to be the case here.